# How to get maximum PK from the table using SQL Server function. If table has no data, it should return 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a function in SQL Server to get the max of id so that I can use it for sequencing

```
create function dbo.DQ_ACC_PROCESS_EXEC_MASTER_SK()
returns bigint 
as
begin
    declare @MAX_PK as BIGINT;

    select @MAX_PK = max(Process_ID) + 1 
    from dbo.DQ_ACC_PROCESS_EXEC_SUMMARY_LOG

    return @MAX_PK;
end;
```

For the first run, the table won't be having any value, so although I am using +1, it does not give me 1 as a return result.

I have also tried with `ISNULL(PROCESS_ID, 1)` and `CASE WHEN PROCESS_ID ISNULL THEN 0 ELSE PROCESS_ID END`. I also tried with `COALESCE`. None of them are returning 1 as a result.

Could you please help. I am new to SQL Server.

Comment: 1) This won't work (correctly) for more than one connection, 2) such functions are performance stoppers for SQL, 3) there are "from the box" solutions which do work well: IDENTITY, SEQUENCE

Comment: Process_ID is IDENTITY?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query

```
select @MAX_PK=ISNULL(max(Process_ID),0)+1 
from dbo.DQ_ACC_PROCESS_EXEC_SUMMARY_LOG
```

It will return `1` if the table have no data, otherwise will return the next `Process_ID`